# Image overflow on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have problem with image overflow on bootstrap. Tryed to put on img also on div. Maybe boostrap is overwriting my styles or something. Can anyone give me a suggestion how to fix this issue?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGUcX.jpg)

http://www.uzdra.lt/studija/

Comment: You should provide some code to look on and some context! See the [MCVE page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You're right. But it's on bootstrap and has many images and other stuff which I need to upload somewhere, and make it work on jsfiddle. So I decided to provide my own link

Answer (score 0):

In your **style.css** *47 number* line.Take a look and add below`css`.Or just 
remove `margin-bottom:-19px;` from `#galerija-seperator` in your `css`.It will be worked.

```
#galerija-seperator {
background-image: url("../img/gallery-seperator.png");
width: 543px;
height: 38px;
overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I describe my problem wrong. It suppose to look like http://postimg.org/image/dfgo5poez/

Comment: @ShameOnU Hello dear, you should upload your code what you tried and be specific of what the problem you faced.Without code it is difficult to find out your whole problem.Here i answered your specific problem which one mentioned above.By the way again i tell , you should provide your code here.